# C# Coinbase Pro API How to Trouble Shoot Responses. 401

Tags: c#, coinbase-api

I keep Getting 401 responses from coinbase pro and I have double checked my passphrase and api key and they are correct. Is there any other reason I would get Unauth response

```
            var timestamp = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString("F0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            var method = "GET";
            var requestPath = "/accounts";
            var body = "";
            var data = timestamp + method + requestPath + body;
            var secret = "***";

            var signedMessage = GetHMACInHex(secret, data);

            var client = new HttpClient()
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.pro.coinbase.com")
            };

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("CB-ACCESS-SIGN", signedMessage);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("CB-ACCESS-KEY", "***");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP", timestamp);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE", "***");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "CoinbaseProClient");
```

This is how I Sign the Data

```
static string GetHMACInHex(string key, string data)
        {
            var decoded = Convert.FromBase64String(key);
            var dataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);


            using (var hmac = new HMACSHA256(decoded))
            {
                
                var hash = hmac.ComputeHash(dataBytes);
                return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I've placed a bounty of 100 imaginary internet points, because I have the same problem. If you did manage to resolve it, please answer your question and enjoy your new internet points.

Comment: I found the answer. The problem was with the content type. Coinbase validate the content type after validating the signature, so you will get a 401 if you didn't specify application/json

Comment: @speciesUnknown that's probably wasn't OP's issue as the http method in the code snippet is `GET`.

Comment: @OfirD you would think so. But whether or not you have anything in the content body, you need a content type header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*401 [status code](https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/error-codes) is returned by Coinbase when following validation of the resource fails on POST or PUT requests:*

- authentication_error-    Invalid auth (generic)
- invalid_token-   Invalid Oauth token
- revoked_token-    Revoked Oauth
  token
- expired_token-    Expired Oauth token

If your problem is not listed here, you may miss to pass `DefaultRequestHeaders`.

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders
      .Accept
      .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

Comment: I would just add a note about why this is needed even if you are doing a GET. Some people can't get their head around how a GET can have a content type header.